# Equalization in CAR- Automotive Audio

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, audio-processing, equalization

Can someone tell me what is the purpose of CAR Equalization in audio and why before CAR Equalization ,gain adjustments are necessary ?
Also why would someone use FIR filters during CAR Equalization process

Can someone answer this please ?

Comment: Are you asking about  Automotive Audio ?

Comment: Yes exactly !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

> what is the purpose of CAR Equalization in audio

Car have a lot of individual speakers in many non-optimal locations. In order to get a good listening experience equalization is used to adjust frequency response and delays for each individual speaker.

> why before CAR Equalization ,gain adjustments are necessary ?

Sorry, I don't understand the question. Gain adjustment is always a part of the equalization process.

> Also why would someone use FIR filters during CAR Equalization process

FIR are occasionally used in tuning tools but rarely in production systems. The required frequency resolution makes FIR VERY long and resource (CPU, memory) inefficient.